# xajax response begins with a blank line

Tags: php, xajax

On my system (running PHP 5.3.15, Apache 2.2.22) xajax works fine.  On another system running PHP 5.2.17, Apache 2.2.22), xajax responses are preceded by a blank line.  This can be seen in the Firebug Network tab, XHR->Response.  There's literally a blank line before

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

What on earth could be causing this and how can I fix it?

Having a blank line before the start of an XML document is an error and leads to the error

```
Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity
```

in the Browser's Error console.

Comment: Look through your PHP includes for a blank line before the opening `<?php`, which is sent as output before the XML response.

Comment: Also look for a blank line following the closing `?>` in any includes run before the XML output.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski it must be something like this - in fact, when I do a view source on the page, it has a blank line before the <!doctype html public "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">.  Perhaps that's causing it.

Comment: Yep that's almost certainly the cause then. You'll just need to go through all your includes and clean the whitespace outside the `<?php ?>`

Comment: Please convert your comment into an answer so I can give you points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look through all the PHP includes which are executed before your expected XML output. It is likely that one or more of them has an errant line break either before the opening `<?php` or following the closing `?>`, which gets passed to the browser as output before the XML header.

```
      <-- Line break
<?php

?>
      <-- Line break
```

If you are on a UNIX-like system, you can use `head` to examine the first line or `tail` to examine the last line of each file.  Look for the file that doesn't begin or end with `<?php / ?>`

```
# In a directory of PHP files...
head -n1 *.php
tail -n1 *.php
```

Comment: This was exactly the issue - someone had accidentally edited one of the includes and added a blank line after what should have been the end.  It's interesting that some coding standards (Such as JetBrains's Code Inspector in PHP Storm) encourage you *not* to specify the closing "?>" to avoid this very problem.  Is there a php flag I could have used to let the interpreter find this problem?

Comment: @ScottWilson I'm not aware of any such flag. Some people use a commit hook in version control to trim whitespace.